# Are there any tools / plugins to develop mapbooks using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, map-book

Are there any tools / plugins to develop mapbooks using QGIS?

Comment: This is something that I plan to do in the future at some time, but if someone else is/has already done work on it then that would be sweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old link is gone.  I am updating the answer with print composer from 2.0
Print composer has new features.
[One of those being map series generation](http://qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/preamble/whats_new.html#map-composer)

Comment: could you please update the link if it still exists?

Comment: hmm. does anybody have access to that forum data any more? I wonder if it is the same thread Ryan references here.

Comment: Perhaps @dassouki could accept Ryan's answer and I will delete mine.

Answer (score 7):

I was just reading the [QGIS User List](http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-user) yesterday and came across the [following post](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2011-June/012444.html):

> I started adding some mapbook
>   functionality [to the EasyPrint Plugin]:
>
> i) Mapbook by grid: You have to create
>   the regular grid first. Paper format,
>   layout, scale etc. values are taken
>   from standard easyprint tab
>   ("simplemap"). You can also choose
>   some overlap percentage. After
>   creating the grid layer you can export
>   the maps. There are some additional
>   parameters like adding adjacent tile
>   indicator to the map or creating an
>   overview map.
>
> ii) Mapbook by feature: This will zoom
>   to the extent of every feature of a
>   specific layer. You can use the layers
>   attributes for setting the title,
>   subtitle, scale and rotation. Scale
>   and rotation will be ignored for
>   polygon and linestring layers.

I gave it a try and it works really well.  Mind you I just made a simple mapbook by zooming to polygon features, but it created them in PDF.  My only wish is that instead of creating a separate PDF for each "page", it was merged into a single PDF document.  It is definitely worth a look!

Comment: yes, it really works like a charm.

Comment: There is an extensive post on creating mapbooks using this plugin at http://darrencope.com/2011/11/22/map-books-in-qgis/.