# How to generate reports from a Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, reports

i hope i can describe my problem. I´m into planning a guidiance system for hiking. And like it is, there will be signs with poi and the distance etc. on it. I´m collecting the data in a shape with a stucture like this:

```
place_id | sign_id | lon | lat | orientation | destination_1 | icons_1 | dist_1 | destination_2 | icons_2 | dist_2 | photo_1 | photo_2 .... and more
```

Now i want to get a single report for every place like this:

[image]

I´ve tried to find a plugin or to get it done over the print composer with no luck.

Every help is welcome, Marc

EDIT: i work on windows with qgis 1.9.90

Comment: What is this thing you speak of -- "print composer"?  It would help if you mentioned your platform :: is this for the web or desktop? Are you running Windows or Linux? ArcGIS, QGIS, SQL Server, PostGres, .NET, Ruby, &c, &c, &c

Comment: Check my old question which is actually similar: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6318/repetitive-automated-mapping-which-platform . One of the answers points towards a mapbookplugin for qgis: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/qgis-producing-mapbooks/11120#11120

Answer (score 3):

Today, I am doing a very similar report(s).

I have got 90 or so points / maps to go....

I am using the print composer in QGIS Trunk. For the shapefile data, that is just an inserted attribute table in the composer. You apply a query to the layer to show only the features of interest in the attribute table. 
I let the composer create a pdf, then using Nitro PDF I paste the photo in as separate process.

There is some value in doing it manually for me since the data needs to be checked.

I'll let you know if I figure any other tricks out.

In the meantime, you may be able to glean some ideas from the template I am using now. I have put it on this new fangled fileshare -
EDIT LINK
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/69791042/Locality%20Landscape%20w%20insert%20map%20trunk.zip

I have attempted to make this template anonymous, ideally you will get some errors + some example layout.

ciao

Comment: Once we got the data sorted out.... the 90 maps took 8 hours. I gave up using the PDF editor to embed the photos, it was simpler and more flexible to use the photo widget in the Print Composer.

Answer (score 2):

Marc, you can try the [Photo2Shape plugin](http://gis-lab.info/qa/photo2shape.html) to quickly get gps-tagged photos into QGIS with an associated shapefile. Available via the Plugin Installer.

For more robust photo keying, with data, consider trying out the [eVis plugin](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/evis/documentation.php) (core, embedded plugin that ships with QGIS). You can enable it in the Plugin Manager.

You may also be interested in [this PDF on georeferencing photos for use in QGIS](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Creating_geo-referenced_photos_for_display_in_QGIS), with some instruction on using the photos with eVis.

Now, concerning getting your photos out via composer, with associated maps, like your layout sketch. I do not think there is a plugin for that, yet. It is certainly doable by using [print templates and PyQGIS](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/composer.html) and by [scripting the setting of the URI for the picture](http://doc.qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerPicture.html), but I'm not sure on exact means of accessing the eVis data via Python (if using eVis). Someone may have experience with printing out eVis data. You may want to [post to the user or developer lists](http://www.qgis.org/en/community.html) for QGIS, in addition to here.

Also, look to print exporting plugins like [Atlas](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/atlas/) and Easy Print for coding logic ideas.

Comment: hi dakcarto, thanks for your reply. i´m actually using all the plugins you listed and i´m into geotagging of photos. i actually got all the data together, but can´t get it out in the right way. Mayby there ist something like a html output similar to google fusion tables.

Comment: Hi Marc. Does your output need to be via print? If not, and you are looking to cater to mobile, have you looked into [QGIS Server](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial) and its [web client](https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client), or [lizmap](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/lizmapwebclient)? Utilizing the WMS QGIS Server, you can craft what you like in [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) and, optionally, [GeoExt](http://www.geoext.org/), which is what QGIS's web client is based on. A very new plugin/server solution is also [QGISCloud](http://qgiscloud.com/).