# How do I batch export maps for sub regions of a dataset with qgis?

Tags: qgis, printing, export, file-formats, batch

I have a national level dataset consisting of polygons, polylines, points and rasters. I would like to export a map for every sub region (border defined by a polygon shapefile). Is there a simple way of doing this in QGIS?

Eventually I would like to be able to offer each sub region as stand alone maps in multiple formats and resolutions.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Atlas QGIS plugin.  I find it much easy to use then the EasyPrint plugin as it allows you to use composers for building the templates.

[image]

Comment: Yep found this late last night! Bit buggy but got it working... excellent tool! Need to ensure that the "coverage" layer is the uppermost for it to work properly!

Comment: @Nathan W, I found the download from http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/atlas/.  Is there an XML repository URL that automatically checks for newer versions?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the EasyPrint plugin.  [Here is an excellent blog article](http://darrencope.com/2011/11/22/map-books-in-qgis/) by @Darren Cope that should help guide you through the process.

Comment: funny just found the plugin 10 seconds before I checked for feedback here! cheers for the link... i will experiment

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4714/qgis-producing-mapbooks